# JavaScript Adding a numeric generated value onto a current set value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that generates a random number for me between 2 values I set myself. Here's the code.

```
<script>
function coinsEarned(){
var worth = document.getElementById("Earned");
var coins=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000+1000);
Earned.value = coins;
}
</script>
```

This works perfect. Now, I have a text bubble that represents the users balance, It is also perfect for me. Here's the code.

```
<input class="balance" id="Balance" type=text" value="20000" readonly/>
```

I would like to add a new button that when clicked will transfer the generated number found above ^^ onto the balance text which is just stated there ^. How would I get this to happen using a JavaScript function preferably so when the button is clicked I will have onclick="funtion();" that will add the generated number to the current balance and then display a new balance.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: What is `Earned.value`? Is this an object that was pre-set before?

Comment: Earned.value is the random number generated for example 3000. I would like to add that onto the balance for example 10000, then display the new balance 13000

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current amount using the `value` attribute.

```
function coinsEarned(){
    var current = document.getElementById("Balance");
    var coins = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000+1000);
    current.value = +current.value + coins;
}

document.getElementById("MyButton").onclick = coinsEarned;
```

Comment: `.value` is a string, so this will do concatenation, not addition.